# I understad why I get: TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tuples

Okey, I have been staring at this two codes for a long time, and I can't get why I receive this error: TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str.

code1.py:
    import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

```
import echoUDP

serveraddress = '0.0.0.0'
serverport = 5002

server2 = (server_address, server_port)
s.bind(server2)
print("Listening on " + server_address + ":" + str(server_port))
s.connect(('0.0.0.0',5005))

while True:
    client_address = ('0.0.0.0.')
    status = 'ok'
    print("Echoing back"+ str(status) + " to " + str(client_address))
    sen = s.sendto(status.encode(),clientaddress)
```

echoUDP.py:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = '0.0.0.0'
server_port = 5005

server = (server_address, server_port)
sock.bind(server)
print("Listening on " + server_address + " Port: " + str(server_port))
sock.connect(('0.0.0.0', 5002))
while True:
    client_address = ('0.0.0.0')
    status = 'ok'
    print("Echoing back "+ str(status) + " to " + str(client_address))
    sen = sock.sendto(status.encode(),client_address)
```

Can someone please tell what I don't get? 
I have read the other problems about tuple, and they get it because their sendto line, the client_address is not a tuple. I thought I created this as a tuple when I write client_address = ('0.0.0.0')?

Comment: Could it be `sen = sock.sendto(status.encode(),client_address)` where `client_address = ('0.0.0.0')` ? No that's not a tuple (test it in *Python* console). Also in the other file, you have `clientaddress`.

Comment: Your client address has to be the hostname AND port. client_address = (('0.0.0.0', 5002))

Comment: `('0.0.0.0')` is not a tuple, it's just a string that you've put in parentheses.  You'd need a trailing comma inside the parentheses to make it a one-element tuple (but, as has already been pointed out, that still wouldn't make the code work because it's expecting a tuple with two elements).

Comment: @Erik you're correct that you have to connect the socket. You ALSO have to enter the full address (host and port) when you use the sock.sento() function. You can't simply enter the hostname, because it also needs a port that is listening for that connection and it expects that argument in the tuple.

Comment: Okey, thank you all for the clearification. Now I get the error of Socket is already connected. Is this because of the line sock.connect(('0.0.0.0',50002)) line?

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo Okey, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `sock.sendto()` should be a tuple containing the host and the port - e.g. `('0.0.0.0', 5005)`. So in your code, use:

```
sen = sock.sendto(status.encode(), (server_address, server_port))
```

As an aside, `('0.0.0.0')` is not a tuple. `('0.0.0.0',)` would be a tuple of length 1. Parentheses are optional for tuple creation in Python - it's the presence of a comma that tells Python that you're creating a tuple. These examples should illustrate.

```
a = 1,
type(a)
>>> tuple

b = 1, 2
type(b)
>>> tuple

c = (1)
type(c)
>>>> int
```